# c #define macro string concatenation

Tags: c, macros

Win7 SP1 32bit, Code Composer Studio v6.1 (I think they are using gcc)

I seem to be having some troubles getting the magic sequence to do the following...

I would like to write a preprocessor #define directive in the format:

(pseudo code)

```
#define extn(x) extern   uint16_t    str_#x
```

then use it, thus:

```
extn(hello);
```

then after preprocessing, have the result look like...

```
extern uint16_t  str_hello;
```

This article in Wikipedia [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)  states:

> "You cannot combine a macro argument with additional text and stringify it all together. You can however write a series of adjacent string constants and stringified arguments: the C compiler will then combine all the adjacent string constants into one long string."

Answer (score 1):

What you want is *concatenation* rather than *stringify*. Hence, use `##`:

```
#define extn(x) extern   uint16_t    str_##x
```